# How to get checked out remote repository directory in github actions

Tags: git, github, github-actions, workspace, git-checkout

I have github actions in repo `knowyrtech/repo1` where I check-out `knowyrtech/repo2` like below:

```
- name: Checkout code from a specific repository and branch
  uses: actions/checkout@v3
  with:
    repository: knowyrtech/repo2 # Replace with the repository you want to checkout
    ref: release/valtech
```

I wish to get to the directory on the windows github runner where `repo2` was checked out.

I used `${{ github.workspace }}` but it takes me to the `<runner work directory>/repo1/repo1` whereas I see that repo2's checkout folder may be here `<runner work directory>/repo1/repo2`.

Can you please suggest how can I get inside the folder where remote `repo2` was checked out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are using multiple repositories within your runner (`repo1/repo1` and `repo1/repo2`), you can use the `path` option from `actions/checkout`.

> **path**
>
> Relative path under $GITHUB_WORKSPACE to place the repository
>
> https://github.com/actions/checkout#usage

```
- name: Checkout
  uses: actions/checkout@v4
  with:
    path: repo1

- name: Checkout knowyrtech/repo2 repo
  uses: actions/checkout@v4
  with:
    repository: knowyrtech/repo2
    ref: release/valtech
    path: repo2
```

This way you shall have the main repo under `repo1` and second repo under `repo2`.